# monacaのInappbrowserを使うと携帯用サイトに飛ばないときがある

Tags: javascript, monaca

私は、monacaを使ってアプリを作成しています。
作成するにあたりわからないことがでてきましたので質問させて頂きます。

monacaのInappbrowserを使うと携帯用サイトに飛ばなくなることがあります。
(携帯用サイトとはpcサイトではなく携帯用サイトに自動変換してくれることです。)
以下は簡易的なコードとなります。

```
sample.html

 <img src="sample1.png" onClick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.co.jp/','_blank','toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top')">
 <img src="sample2.png" onClick="window.open('http://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/?sc_e=ytc','_blank', 'toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top')">
```

飛ばす先は仮にyahooさんとしていますが、実際は違うサイトとなります。
また、実際はimgタグを何個も使用してwindow.openでサイトに飛ばしています。

上記のプログラムを使ってサイトに飛ばすと一部は携帯用サイトに変換してくれます。
例えば実際にはないと思いますがhttp://www.yahoo.co.jp/がhttp://www.yahoo.co.jp/smartphoneに変換します。

次にhttp://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/?sc_e=ytcに飛んだ場合、携帯サイトではなくPCサイトになり、レイアウトが崩れてしまいます。このあとにhttp://www.yahoo.co.jp/にアクセスしても携帯用サイトではなくpcサイトになってしまいました。しばらくするとhttp://www.yahoo.co.jp/は携帯用サイトにアクセスできるようになりますが。

これは相手のサイトが携帯用サイトとして作成していないことによりこのような現象になるのでしょうか？
また、初めはhttp://www.yahoo.co.jp/は携帯用サイトに飛んでましたがhttp://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/?sc_e=ytcを踏むことによりなぜ次にhttp://www.yahoo.co.jp/はpcサイトになったのでしょうか？

ご教授よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 何の情報を元にPC、スマートフォンなどの判別を行っていると思いますか？スマートフォン用URLを最初から指定しておけば悩む必要もないかなぁと思いますが。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。すみません、私の知識不足で何の情報を元にスマホ判別を行っているのはよくわかっておりません。質問内容は簡易的なコードだったため実際はwindow.openの第一引数に入るURLはAPIを使って変更できるようにしております。私がURLを変える分にはPCサイトを入力しませんが、知らない方が入力した場合どうしたらよいものかと悩んでおります。もし、PCサイトに入った場合は、キャッシュを消すパラメータを書けばいいかと思いましたが、SNS等がログアウトしてしまうためこの案はできなくなりました。これ以外で質問内容のyahooさんの例を解消する方法はあるのでしょうか？よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: その問題が発生するURLを提示していただくことはできませんか？ちなみに質問に書かれたHTML（とリンク先）をMonacaデバッガ―で試してみましたが、再現しませんでした。 / もし普通のブラウザアプリでも同じ現象が起きるのであれば、サーバー側であえてそのような仕様にしている可能性もあります。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。URLは、こちらの都合により提示することができないです。すみません。こちらでわかったことがありまして、原因としてはURLにPCとかかれていましたのでPC用のURLに入っていたことがわかりました。そのURLに入ったあと、今まで携帯用サイトに飛んでいたURLがPCサイトに飛ぶようになりました。携帯サイトに飛ばずなぜPCサイトに飛ぶようになったのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: URLを記載しなければ話になりませんよ。

Comment: 返信遅くなりました。こちらの都合で情報が提示できなくてすみません。質問の回答をして頂きありがとうございました。